# How to add AdMob ads to a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, admob, cell

I am trying to add an AdMob ad to a table view.

I would like it to show up in every 10th cell. (Eg. like how it is in the Free version of the Reddit App if you have it).

I tried to follow the AdMob documentation but I didn't have any luck and I'm sure there is something I am missing.

Could anyone shine some light on a simple way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've used code basically like this:

```
int row = [indexpath row];

if (0 == (row % 10)) {  // or 9 == if you don't want the first cell to be an ad!
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"AdCell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    [cell.contentView addSubview:[AdMobView requestAdWithDelegate:self]];
} else {
     // make your normal cells
}
```

Comment: This indeed does work nicely except that the ads shown are all the same. The first one or two are unique then after that, the ReusableCell system kicks in and you get recycled ads. I did it like this: 

  static NSString* MyIdentifier;
  NSInteger row = [indexpath row];
  MyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"AdCell%d", row];

Comment: What about datasource return count?

Comment: When tableview scrolling at that time ad will be flicker @David Maymudes