# Adding Native Admob AdUnit Every 2nd Row In TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, admob

I'm having trouble adding an AdUnit in a TableView after every 2nd row. I have found someone trying in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583583/how-to-add-admob-ads-to-a-uitableview) but I cant get it going in Swift. Nothing seems to show up, not even a break in my cells to show that something is happening on the 2nd cell. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var nativeExpressAdView: GADNativeExpressAdView!
let request = GADRequest()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     nativeExpressAdView.adUnitID = “{adUnitIDNumber}”
     nativeExpressAdView.rootViewController = self
  }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let post = posts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    if (0 == (indexPath.row % 2)) {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell") as? FeedPostCell {

            cell.contentView.addSubview(nativeExpressAdView!)
            nativeExpressAdView.loadRequest(request)

        } else {
            return FeedPostCell()

        }

    } else {

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell") as? FeedPostCell {
            cell.postImg.image = UIImage(named:"placeholderImg")
            cell.delegate = self

            if let img = feedViewController.imageCache.object(forKey: post.imageUrl as NSString) {
            cell.configureCell(post, img: img)
            } else {
            cell.configureCell(post)
            }
            return cell
        } else {

        return FeedPostCell()
        }

    }
    return FeedPostCell()
}
```

Comment: Convert it to Swift: https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/